# Getting incorrect max and min values for exponential values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, max, min, exponential

I am getting incorrect max and min values using max() and np.max() for the sort of values I have given in the code script. I have arrays that is filled with values similar to these three values.

Edit: It seems I had a brain freeze, my apologies, the values are correct. I cannot believe I was stuck here for 2 hours. Feel free to delete or flag this post.

```
import numpy as np

c = 0.0000e+00
d = 2.2141e-42
e = 9.1835e-41

max([c,d,e]) # Returns 9.1835e-41
np.max(np.array([c,d,e])) # Returns 9.1835e-41

min([c,d,e]) # Returns 0.0
np.min(np.array([c,d,e])) # Returns 0.0
```

Comment: Those results seem correct.

Comment: what do you expect the min and max to be? ... that seems right

Comment: can you try it with    np.argmax and np.argmin  .  work?

Comment: @Gautamrk what is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: `9.1835e-41` is `9.1835` with decimal point pushed to left 41 positions so it is greater then 0

Answer (score 1):

Written in decimal notation, not scientific notation, your numbers turn out to be:

```
c = 0
d = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000022141
e = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000091835
```

I would say c is the smallest and e is the largest, which seems to match what `max` and `np.max` think as well.